# Feed Import from multiple pages

Tags: 7, nodes, feeds, importing-exporting

Make Feed Importer go to given URL which has a list of thumbnails and links to their pages and make it check/open each of those links and scrape content from there into unique nodes importing its titles and images and so on and so on?

Is this possible or does the content has to be listed in one single page to scrape it?

I've done it with just scraping from one page or .xml feed, but how do I tell my feed to check that one page for links and go to those links and scrape content from each and every link?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`hook_feeds_after_save`](http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/misc/feeds!feeds.api.php/function/hook_feeds_after_save/7.x)`( $source, $entity, $item, $entity_id)`
for parsing for links the document and execute command after the importing of each feed.